# Java Swing - Keeping reasonable dimensions on different screens

Tags: java, swing, interface

I have just completed an application for my final year project and I need to create the interface for it now. The application will not include many different screens, just one introduction screen with a simple tutorial and the main screen with 5 `JPanel` and a `JMenu`. I have each part of the application providing its own `JPanel`, and the GUI I am about to make should put all those panels together and provide the intro.

> What I want to ask is how I can properly set the sizes of different
>   components so that they are displayed the same on different screen sizes.(not getting really close to each other on small screens / big blank spaces on larger screens)

Should I manually set their preferred sized based on some percentage of the screen dimensions ?(e.g. 20% * width,40% * height) Or there is some other way to do it ?

Also, having one week ahead to complete this part, would it be any benefit to try and learn some library like MigLayout? I read a lot that is easier to use than standard Swing.

p.s

The JPanels include trees,textAreas,toolBar, buttons,checkboxes,comboboxes and textfields. Each one of those panels are quite simple to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this type of question is pretty application dependent, simply because what is 'reasonable' depends on the application and user expectations, but...

If you want the content of the frame to dictate the size of each frame, you can just call frame.pack() and an appropriate size will be guessed at based on the size requirements of the frame's children.

However, if it makes more sense to let the screen size dictate the frame dimensions, you can use Toolkit.getScreenSize() to get the screen size and do your positioning based on what you find.

Comment: What I mean by reasonable: I have a picture of the UI on my head (and on paper). I want that on my screen regardless of the size. If screen gets bigger things should get bigger while having same relative dimensions. Id guess answer is getting the percentage?

Comment: You should be able to scale the window dimensions with Toolkit.getScreenSize() and do the calculations yourself, as they are usually very easy.  If you used GridBagLayout you can also specify how any 'extra' space gets divided between components within the frame itself.

Comment: GridBagLayout is confusing for most people. The key idea here is to use a LayoutManager. This will position and scale the components inside a container according to the available space. The swing tutorial has a nice section about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html